# Magento2 Luma make special price show after original price

Tags: magento2, price

On magento 2.2.5 product detail page when I set a catalog price or or a special price what happens is the special price is shown first and then under it is the original price listed. i want to change this so that the original price is always listed first (above) any special price.

In my `app/design/frontend/luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view` I see a price_cloned.phtml which idk what that does I tried editing the final_price.phtml (since this is for simple products) but that didn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

Copy the following file:

> magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

to:

> magento_root/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

And use the below code for **final_price.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks that doesnt work. So what I have is I am using the luma theme and customizing it. so I took the entire magento_root/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma folder and copied its contents to magento_root/app/design/frontend/luma . I then edit the file in the magento_root/app/design/frontend/luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml . file but that doesn't work. it still seems to load it from the vendor folder. i also tried compiling and deploying even though I am in developer mode. No matter what I do it seems to load it from the vendor folder?

Comment: you are doing wrong. What is your theme? It should be app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/......

Comment: My theme is app/design/frontend/kiss/luma/ and then inside the luma folder I have a folder Magento_Catalog/templates/

Comment: Correct. It should work then

Answer (score 0):

You have to override this file:

> \app\design\frontend\kiss\luma\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml

Overridden code is here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All this tested in my fresh setup, Also adding image here please check

[image]

Have updated file path as per your theme package please check.

Comment: when I move the file to my app/design/frontend/Magento_Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml clear cache but it doesnt seem to be referencing/using that file?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my ans pls check.